# Strange "cache" effect between client and server

Tags: java, sockets, caching, serialization

I use a Socket-based connection between Client and server with ObjectOutputStream.

The objects serialized and exchanged have this structure:

```
public class RichiestaSalvataggioArticolo implements Serializable {

        private ArticoloDati articolo;

        public RichiestaSalvataggioArticolo(ArticoloDati articolo) {
                this.articolo = articolo;

        }

        @Override
        public void ricevi(GestoreRichieste gestore) throws Exception {
                gestore.interpreta(this);                    
        }


        public ArticoloDati getArticolo() {
                return articolo;
        }

}
```

the issue is that when I try to exchange messages between C/S with incapsulated content very similar (ArticoloDati whom differ only in 2 fields out of 10), the Client sends an ArticoloDati, but the Server receives the previous one.

**Does the ObjectOutputStream implement some kind of cache or memory between the calls, that fails to recognize that my 2 objects are different because they are very similar?**

Comment: Have you tried flushing after each time you output something to the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable "back-references" in serialization, so use [`ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Writes an "unshared" object to the `ObjectOutputStream`. This method is identical to `writeObject`, except that it always writes the given object as a new, unique object in the stream (as opposed to a back-reference pointing to a previously serialized instance).

It's good practice to couple this with [`ObjectInputStream.readUnshared`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readUnshared%28%29) in some cases -- this one included.

Comment: I need to do some testing, but I accept the answer, that's what I needed to know

Comment: @mark your `RichiestaSlavataggioArticolo` object has the same identity, only its state has changed; it's prior serialized copy (with out-of-date state) is memorized on the server side and the client only writes a reference to a previously serialized object. This behavior is intentional and can be avoided using the unshared methods.